# How can use transparent color in QColorDialog for clear background color of text?

Tags: qt

I use `QColorDialog` and `execCommand() hilite` for changing background color of text. I changed background color of a part of my text to red for example, And again I want to clear the background color to transparent (Not white).

How can I do this? Is there a way to add transparent color option to `QColorDialog`? Or what?

Thank You,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use static `QColorDialog::getColor` function, pass `QColorDialog::ShowAlphaChannel` as the 4th argument.

If you use `QColorDialog` object, use `dialog.setOption(QColorDialog::ShowAlphaChannel)`.

Comment: Thank you, and then I can check the (alpha == 0) condition and pass the transparent to execcommand hilite :)